# SQLCMD is not working in pre-deployment script in sql project

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I have sql project in visual studio and I created pre-deployment script

```
/*
 Pre-Deployment Script Template                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 This file contains SQL statements that will be executed before the build script.   
 Use SQLCMD syntax to include a file in the pre-deployment script.          
 Example:      :r .\myfile.sql                              
 Use SQLCMD syntax to reference a variable in the pre-deployment script.        
 Example:      :setvar TableName MyTable                            
               SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

:setvar TableName MyTable                           
SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]
```

but Iam getting an error at `:setvar` line

```
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
```

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

You need to switch to `SQLCMD` mode in Visual Studio via the menu *SQL > Execution Settings*.

You can also have all SQL files open in `SQLCMD mode` by default if you dig into *Options > SQL Server Tools > Query Execution*.